# How to .gitignore files recursively

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm trying to avoid the following pattern in my `.gitignore` file.

```
MyPrject/WebApp/Scripts/special/*.js
MyPrject/WebApp/Scripts/special/*/*.js
MyPrject/WebApp/Scripts/special/*/*/*.js
MyPrject/WebApp/Scripts/special/*/*/*/*.js
MyPrject/WebApp/Scripts/special/*/*/*/*/*.js
MyPrject/WebApp/Scripts/special/*/*/*/*/*/*.js
MyPrject/WebApp/Scripts/special/*/*/*/*/*/*/*.js
```

We tried:

```
MyPrject/WebApp/Scripts/special/**.js
MyPrject/WebApp/Scripts/special/**/*.js
```

This however didn't work. This is git on Windows. Is there a more concise way to do this without repeating things?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correctly ignore all files recursively under a specific folder except for a specific file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812717/correctly-ignore-all-files-recursively-under-a-specific-folder-except-for-a-spec)

Answer (score 176, accepted):

As of git 1.8.2, this:

```
MyPrject/WebApp/Scripts/special/**/*.js
```

Should work according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812717/correctly-ignore-all-files-recursively-under-a-specific-folder-except-for-a-spec). It also works for me in Windows 7 using Sourcetree 1.6.12.0 and the version of git that it installs (1.8.4-preview20130916).

To gitignore every file and folder under a directory recursively:

```
MyPrject/WebApp/Scripts/special/**
```

Comment: What about prior to git 1.8?

Comment: If this answer does not work (on Windows), add the character `/` at the beginning. Example: `/MyProject/WebApp/Scripts/special/**/*.js`

Comment: I'm embarrassed that my answer keeps getting upvotes when it is literally a link to *another* answer.

Comment: I can confirm that neither `/WebApp/Scripts/special/**/*.js` nor `*.js` works when put in `/WebApp/Scripts/special/.gitignore`, but when I put `*.js` in `/WebApp/Scripts/special/a/b/c/.gitignore` it does work.

Comment: @puk : the `.gitignore` in this question was in the repo root (parent directory of `/Webapp`).

Comment: Your answer looks good but didn't work for me on Windows 10 with git 1.9.1 for ignoring all files except js in following case: (first line) `foo/bar/*/*`
(second line) `!foo/bar/**/*.js` It worked only for one level of subdirectories, but not recursively.

Answer (score 28):

Following gitignore manual page:

> [...] git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for
>     consumption by fnmatch(3) with the FNM_PATHNAME flag: wildcards in
>     the pattern will not match a / in the pathname.

So, this clearly stands that there is no way to specify *a certain amount of directories* between two strings, like between `special` and `js`.

Nevertheless, you can have a `.gitignore` file per directory, so maybe in your case the following content

```
*.js
```

at the following place

```
MyPrject/WebApp/Scripts/special/.gitignore
```

would be sufficient?

Comment: I used to have `MyPrject/WebApp/Scripts/special*.js` and it matched `MyPrject/WebApp/Scripts/specialfile.js` as well as `MyPrject/WebApp/Scripts/special/a/b/c/file.js`. However, for some reason the behavior has changed and my current workaround is to list directories individually. I'm using GitHub for Windows.

Comment: e.g. `find MyPrject/WebApp/Scripts/special -type d -printf 'echo "*.js" >> %h/.gitignore\n git add %h/.gitignore\n' | sh`

Answer (score 26):

This works for me in on osx.

```
lib64/**/__pycache__/
lib/**/__pycache__/
*.py[cod]
.ipynb_checkpoints/
**/.ipynb_checkpoints/
.DS_Store
**/.DS_Store
```

Comment: I accidentally downvoted your answer and I am unable to fix it unless you edit. If you can edit it and just put a space or next line. I will fix the vote.

Answer (score 6):

Try executing `git rm -r --cached MyPrject/WebApp/Scripts/special/`
Your mentioned directory might have been cached by git and will show up on untracked files.
After clearing the cache make sure you have it mentioned on `.gitignore`.