# Cant add target folder to .gitignore

Tags: java, spring, git, bitbucket

I have Spring module project on *Bitbucket* with 2 Spring Boot apps in it. In the root module I have the *.gitignore* file and in every app I have *.gitignore* file with this content :

```
config.properties
.classpath
.project
.settings/
.idea/
target/
*.iml
```

I tried pulling project again but no changes.
Config.properties do get ignored but target folder isn't. Every time I make some change, I get target folder file in my git changes list.

[image: target folder files in git]

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple possibilities that come to mind.

1. Ensure that you haven't yet committed the `target/` folder. This would prevent the gitignore from doing its job and ignoring the added folder.
2. The other thought is you have a multi-module project. Ensure you are calling the correct `target/` folder to ignore: [How to .gitignore files recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550688/how-to-gitignore-files-recursively)

Comment: Number 1 helped me , thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 5):

The new patterns in the gitignore don´t work for existing directories.
Make sure to remove the existing entries in the git for the target folders:

```
git rm -r --cached etplans-web/target
```

Comment: I executed this command and after that git ls-files this one, and target folder wasn't on list. Now when i check status with git status, i have a ton of deleted files from target folder. Should i commit that or ?

Comment: @user3364181 Try to make a commit and check if the gitignores respects your pattern (target/) now

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your "target/" folder path is correct. Look for examples [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Answer (score 0):

i think its because you've accidentally added a file in target directory and so git doesn't ignore it. 
hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/how-to-undo-git-add-before-commit) would help

Comment: `git ls-files` will list all the files which are under git's super vision

Comment: i didnt, eclipse build files after changes and then add them to target folder